# Jasperreports: How to pass main dataset parameters to subdataset for multiaxis chart?

Tags: jasper-reports

I chose subdataset parameters as:

`subdataset_parameter = $P{dataset_parameter}`

but still chart doesn't work (it doesn't show any data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't configure it at subdataset level. You have to configure Parameters at the level:

Multi Axis / [...] Plot / Dataset

[image: outline report]

and then configure parameters

[image: dataset properties]

as follows:

[image: dataset parameters]